# Removing underlining from certain elements inside a <u>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using a Chrome plugin to apply custom stylesheet tweaks to someone else's website (i.e. I can't change the HTML).

I would like to stop underlining italic (`<i>`) text inside an underline (`<u>`) element, while retaining normal underlining for other parts inside the `<u>`.

For example these are the kind of thing I'm after:

```
<u>Foo</u>                --> Foo (underlined)
<u><i>Bar</i></u>         --> Bar (not underlined)
<u>Foo <i>Bar</i></u>     --> Foo (underlined) Bar (not underlined)
```

I tried:

```
u i {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

But found that changing the text-decoration for the `<i>` makes no difference. The outer `<u>` seems to be the one that determines the text-decoration.

Is there a way to do this?

I understand this might be a duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)
but hoping someone might be able to come up with a clever workround for this specific case.

Comment: don't use u tags for underlining in html 5 - it's semantic meaning has changed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u.  Same with italic and the i tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

Comment: I understand that. As I said, it's someone else's website!

Comment: The first thing in my mind after reading your question is using pseudo element to simulate the underline.

Comment: no thats no going to work as the parent `<u>` style is for the whole element and `<i>`is just a child that can have its own underline. there is no way in css to do something like `u:not-child-text { text-decoration: none; }`. i think it could be done with javascript, but as you are using a plugin (fiddler) to insert css on top, i guess there is no way

Comment: Oops...answered and then realised it's a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Apply `display:inline-block` to the child NOT to be underlined.

```css
u {
font-size:3rem
}

u i {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<u>Foo <i>Bar</i></u>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `white` color to `text-decoration-color` of`i`

```css
u i {
    text-decoration: white solid underline;
}
```

```html
<u>Foo <i>Bar</i></u>
```

Comment: Thanks! I love Stack Overflow! Both of the main answers here work (although I suppose have minor side-effects). I've upvoted them both, but I'm going to accept Paulie_D's because it's the one I've decided to use.

Comment: use what you want to :) I really happy to help ; happy coding